# Importar módulos específicos é mais rápido/performático que importar tudo (com o asterisco)?

Tags: python, desempenho

Em Python, desde quando percebi que é possível importar funções ou classes específicas de um módulo, optei por sempre fazer assim. Um dos motivos é a legibilidade. O outro motivo eu não tenho certeza, por isso queria tirar essa dúvida: performance.

Suponhamos que temos num módulo com um número considerável de funções e classes.

Exemplo 1:

```
from biblioteca import a, b, c, D
```

Exemplo 2:

```
from biblioteca import *
```

Com relação aos exemplos acima:

- É correto dizer que importar de um módulo apenas aquilo que se vai usar é mais performático do que usar o asterisco? Ou isso não faz diferença alguma em Python?
- É uma boa ideia usar o *, mesmo que existam coisas sendo importadas, as quais eu não vou usar?
- Existe diferença performática entre `form biblioteca import *` e `import biblioteca`?

Comment: @renan no caso específico, eu quero fazer um tira teima entre esses dois. Mas já que você tocou no assunto, vou fazer uma edição :p

Answer (score 5):

O tempo é exatamente o mesmo  -
a diferença está na legibilidade que o seu próprio código vai ter -

No exemplo que você mesmo coloca

```
from biblioteca import *
...
# 300 linhas depois
...
for elemento in a:
   fca_coisas(elemento, b)
```

Então - de onde vieram "a" e "b" ?
Quando você importa elementos com o nome específico tanto quem está lendo o seu código (em geral você mesmo), quanto as ferramentas de programação, como IDEs e linters de código, conseguem saber de onde veio cada nome (de variável, classe ou módulo) que você está usando no seu código.

Um único `from x import *` acaba com a funcionalidade de qualquer ferramenta que te avise se voce estar usando uma variável inexistente, por exemplo - já que a ferramenta não tem como saber se o nome que você digitou não foi importado junto com o `*`

Em Python 3 inclusive, por uma questão de otimização de acesso as variáveis locais na implementação padrão, passou a ser *erro de sintaxe* usar um `from x import *` dentro de uma função - porque dessa forma o compilador não tem como saber, antes de executar o código, quais serão as variáveis locais da função, e quais ele teria que buscar como variáveis não-locais ou globais.

Esclarecido isso, vamos ver suas dúvidas específicas:

- É correto dizer que importar de um módulo apenas aquilo que se vai
  usar é mais performático do que usar o asterisco?

Não.

- Ou isso não faz
  diferença alguma em Python?

Isso não faz a menor diferença em Python - de qualquer forma o módulo alvo é compilado por inteiro - mesmo que ele tenha 300 declarações de funções e vocẽ vá usar apenas uma. (mas claro, existem várias formas de escrever o código que, caso isso vá fazer diferença - e quase nunca vai fazer - você possa de fato só compilar e importar o que vá precisar).

- É uma boa ideia usar o *, mesmo que
  existam coisas sendo importadas, as quais eu não vou usar?

Nunca é uma boa idéia usar o `*`. Ou quase nunca - há execeções, como bibliotecas que expõem constantes ou nomes para o trabalho interativo.
Exemplos de código com Pyqt, NumPy e Pygame frequentemente vem com  `from x import  *`  - mas mesmo assim, para um projeto de médio porte, vale a pena usar `import nome_grande_da_biblioteca as x`, e acessar as coisas como `x.CONSTANTE, x.funcao_1` - do que usar o `*`.

- Existe
  diferença performática entre form biblioteca import * e import
  biblioteca?

Não. Exceto para um import dentro de uma função em Python 2.x - nesse caso, todo o código numa função que contenha um `import *` vai ser mais lento, por que o Python não pode otimizar o acesso às variáveis locais.

Comment: Muito obrigado, esclarecedor. No final das contas, a utilidade fica mais para o lado da organização do que do desempenho. +1

Comment: @jsbueno editei alguns erros de ortografia na sua postagem, palavras com letras faltando ou invertidas. Não prejudicam o entendimento, mas ajudam ne...

Comment: Me lembra de marcar e ler a resposta :D